# Is it possible to use ssis to upload XML files to a SQL server

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd, etl

Software used by my company generates thousands of XML files. I need to upload the data contained within to a SQL server for reporting.

I intend to use SSIS to upload the data. I have created a for each loop to read each of the files and pass the file name as a variable to a data flow task. The DFT will read each XML and upload it to the SQL table. I am having trouble getting the DFT to read the XML though.

I generated an XSD file but it is not reading the XML as I need it to. Unfortunately the software is 3rd party and used by other companies so we are unable to adjust the XMLs. The only thing I can change is the XSD or the SSIS package.

Here is the XML

```
<SOFTWAREDATA>
  <version>4</version>
  <date>2018-04-26</date>
  <start_time>13:39:15</start_time>
  <end_time>13:40:14</end_time>
  <user>user</user>
  <group>stn</group>
  <sequence>stn</sequence>
  <line_path>company</line_path>
  <line_path>location</line_path>
  <line_path>productionline</line_path>
  <training_file>filename.txt</training_file>
  <model>model</model>
  <variant>model-RHD</variant>
  <difficulty_level>1</difficulty_level>
  <no_of_operations>1</no_of_operations>
  <no_of_overview_questions>0</no_of_overview_questions>
  <no_of_correct_operations>1</no_of_correct_operations>
  <no_of_wrong_operation>0</no_of_wrong_operation>
  <no_of_missed_operation>0</no_of_missed_operation>
  <no_of_wrong_tool>0</no_of_wrong_tool>
  <no_of_wrong_prop>0</no_of_wrong_prop>
  <no_of_wrong_answers>0</no_of_wrong_answers>  
  <no_of_wrong_overview_answers>0</no_of_wrong_overview_answers>
  <no_of_wrong_direction>0</no_of_wrong_direction>
  <no_of_tool_help>0</no_of_tool_help>
  <no_of_part_help>0</no_of_part_help>
  <no_of_show_operation_help>0</no_of_show_operation_help>
  <no_of_info_help>0</no_of_info_help>
  <no_of_navigation_help>0</no_of_navigation_help>
  <no_of_operation_list_help>0</no_of_operation_list_help>
  <was_sequence_completed_ok>true</was_sequence_completed_ok>
  <priority_mode>false</priority_mode>
  <version_info>info</version_info>
  <build>404</build>
  <revision>51</revision>
  <errors>0</errors>
</SOFTWAREDATA>
```

and here is the XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="SOFTWAREDATA">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="version" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="date" type="xs:date" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="start_time" type="xs:time" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="end_time" type="xs:time" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="user" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="group" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sequence" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="line_path" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="training_file" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="model" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="variant" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="difficulty_level" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_operations" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_overview_questions" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_correct_operations" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_wrong_operation" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_missed_operation" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_wrong_tool" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_wrong_prop" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_wrong_answers" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_wrong_overview_answers" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_wrong_direction" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_tool_help" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_part_help" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_show_operation_help" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_info_help" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_navigation_help" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="no_of_operation_list_help" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="was_sequence_completed_ok" type="xs:boolean" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="priority_mode" type="xs:boolean" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="version_info" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="build" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="revision" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="errors" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I am new to working with XMLs except for in power query where the files are read no problem (there are too many files to use power query). I was expecting to see a table with one row and each element name as a column header and the values in the row.

When I try to read the file in SSIS it only picks up the "line_path" column:

[image]

Is it possible to do what I am trying to achieve by changing either the package or the XSD?

Comment: I always use c# script component (load) to read XML files. You want to create a class (either use the XSD.exe tool with the XSD or paste the XML as special to a class) and then use XML desierializer.

Comment: I guess I usually do it that way because I use other tools (like WebClient to get the XML from an API) to get the data and my XML usually has nested lists to handle.

Comment: unfortunately I dont know c# so what you described isn't currently an option. I have however found an alternate approach

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might stumble upon this post I have found a solution...

Instead of using an XML source, I created some M code in Excel Power Query and used that inside a power query source. I was able to access all XMLs at once in a table and upload that to SQL rather than looping over each file individually.

Feel free to contact me if you want more details on this solution.